# Bug with window resizing

Tags: window, 23.10, window-management, 24.04

I have reproduced this on both 23.10 and the not yet released 24.04.

[image: Window bug]

What happens is when you try to maximize a window by dragging it upwards, The system shows two "outlines" instead of one. You can see that clearly in the video provided (maybe not *that* clearly, but we have what we have).

One outline is "half" of the screen and the other is "full". Am I the only one experiencing this or is this a Ubuntu bug? Is there a solution (or a temporary workaround)?

Thank you in advance.